# Use select result for WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table {id | date}. I want to select all rows where date > date from the given row.

Normally I would do it in two queries:

```
SELECT `date` FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`={id}; //get {date} from known {id}
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `date`> {date} //get the desired result
```

Is it possible to do it in one SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: `Is it possible to do it in one SQL query?` Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from mytable where date > (select date from mytable where id = {id})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for a [self-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join).

```
SELECT o.*
FROM mytable t         -- For every row from This table,
CROSS JOIN mytable o   -- and for every row in the Other (see note #2) table
WHERE t.id <> o.id     -- such that it is a different row
  AND o.date > t.date  -- with a date later
  AND t.id = {id}      -- than a specific row.
```

Notes:

1. Because `>` is used in the value comparison, the `t.id <> o.id` clause can be omitted. In any case, the query planner should figure this stuff out just fine.
2. The CROSS JOIN starts off a Cartesian product but the WHERE filters bring it back down quickly. In particular the `t.id = {id}` clause (assuming that `id` has a unique constraint) brings down the multiplicity to at most one output row for each input row in `o`.